I have a configuration error : ( Error: build entry field required for the electron vite main config ) in electron-vite library
I tried to change my file name inside the main folder to:
app.ts
windows.ts
ipcMain.ts
1: https://i.sstatic.net/AhrBw58J.png
i ran into this problem, and honestly, I'm not familiar with configuring Rollup or Vite.js because I haven't used them before. So, I need some help with this and a quick explanation about how to configure Vite and Rollup regarding the electron-vite library.
I tried to modify it according to what is explained in Rollup and Vite, but I encountered other errors, such as not being able to place the files app.ts, windows.ts, or ipcMain.ts. I searched a lot for solutions but couldn't find any. Also, I'm not proficient in reading English and face difficulties while reading, as reading generally is challenging. Please help.

NOTE!: im using this Electron-vite library NOT this library
here's my electron.vite.config file :
import { resolve } from "path"
import { defineConfig, externalizeDepsPlugin } from "electron-vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"

export default defineConfig({
  main: {
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin()]
  },
  preload: {
    plugins: [externalizeDepsPlugin()]
  },
  renderer: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@renderer": resolve("src/renderer/frontend")
      }
    },
    plugins: [react()]
  }
})

I'm trying to solve a problem that I encountered, and I've searched for it a lot but couldn't find a clear solution. Also, I'm unfamiliar with some libraries and need a clear and concise explanation of my problem to understand it better and pay attention to it in the future.

Have you read the docs of electron-vite? The answer is just here.
